# Is there any way to append FormData and URLSearchParam in a single request using axios?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to connect a backend with a third-party API.
But I got stuck when trying to append the request body using the form-data package because the package is not supported in appending an array. In my case, the third-party request body is requiring two mandatory fields which are document (file) and signature (array of JSON).

I was trying to replace the form data using URLSearchParam but then the file cannot be appended to the URLSearchParam, is there any way to combine these two methods so I could append a file and an array to the request body